# Can I use responses of a previous google form in a new google form?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google form that is collecting the Event date, event name, employee name, and his/her assistance in that event(Yes/No). After collecting those answers, we want to use the data to create another Google form using the Event date, event name, and employee name and add other questions. The key point here is to take all employees that answered Yes from the first Google form only and avoid entry of the data from the first form within the second form manually. Each form will manage by two different end users. Is there a way to accomplish it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications!  Please  edit your question to include an example/mockup of each of the spreadsheets including some sample data. Identify in the first the columns that will be included in the second, and in the second the columns that are pulled from the first. You only need a few row of sample data, but please include the examples as markdown tables and/or images so everything needed to understand the problem is included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the destination spreadsheet of the first form, use a formula or a script to generate **edit response URLs** that point to the second form and contain [pre-filled answers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839588?hl=en&sjid=3121209625290389041-EU#zippy=%2Csend-a-form-with-pre-filled-answers) that will be automatically included when the second form is opened through that URL.

Note that edit response URLs contain IDs of form fields, and those IDs vary between forms. You will have to replace field IDs in the edit response URL with the IDs of the second form.

Use `filter()` to get the email addresses and edit response URLs of the users who answered **Yes**, and use a mail merge add-on to email those URLs to those users, asking them to open the second form through the URL they received.

See [Assign Edit URL](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/174662012?msgid=174700513) for sample code.